# Group by percentage not working as a percent of the total group

Tags: r, dplyr

I've scoured the web and stack, but haven't had luck trying multiple things. I have a dataset that I'm trying to get a grouping calculation, but also a percentage of that group. Here's an example of what I am getting:

```
    structure(list(Advanced = c("Task5", "Advanced", "0", "2", "1", 
" 8.500000", "0.0", "3.191667", "25.00000", "4.500000", "0.6428571", 
"4.50", "0.6428571", "4.500000", "0.6428571", "5.000000", "0.7142857", 
"6.500000", "0.9285714", "2", "1.00", NA, NA), Advanced = c("Task5", 
"Advanced", "1", "4", "1", "26.500000", "0.5", "9.037500", "63.25000", 
"6.000000", "0.8571429", "4.75", "0.6785714", "5.250000", "0.7500000", 
"6.000000", "0.8571429", "5.250000", "0.7500000", "1", "0.25", 
"4.333333", "0.6190476"), Novice = c("Task5", "Novice", "0", 
"2", "1", " 6.000000", "0.0", "4.850000", "49.00000", "6.500000", 
"0.9285714", "6.00", "0.8571429", "6.000000", "0.8571429", "6.500000", 
"0.9285714", "6.500000", "0.9285714", "2", "1.00", NA, NA), Novice = c("Task5", 
"Novice", "1", "6", "1", " 7.666667", "1.0", "8.672222", "69.83333", 
"5.333333", "0.7619048", "4.00", "0.5714286", "3.833333", "0.5476190", 
"4.333333", "0.6190476", "4.166667", "0.5952381", "0", "0.00", 
"4.000000", "0.5714286")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Task", 
"segment", "t5_pass_fail", "N", "SuccessRate", "UniquePages", 
"Timedout_percent", "TimeonTask", "Clicks", "Useful_raw", "Useful_percent", 
"UserFriendly_raw", "UserFriendly_percent", "Learned_raw", "Learned_percent", 
"Satisfied_raw", "Satisfied_percent", "Confident_raw", "Confident_percent", 
"Experienced_Difficulty_raw", "Experienced_Difficulty_percent", 
"difficulty_level_raw", "difficulty_level_percent"))
```

The process to get the above is from the following:

```
    Task5_Strict <- cleanuxq4 %>% 
  dplyr:: select(("urespid_0"),("segment"),starts_with("t")) %>%
  group_by (segment,t5_pass_fail)%>%
  summarize(
    Task = "Task5",
    N =n(),
    SuccessRate = ((t5_pass_fail = 1)/sum(t5_pass_fail)),
    UniquePages = (mean(t5_unique_pageviews)),
    Timedout_percent = sum(t5_effectiveness)/N,
    TimeonTask = mean(t5_time_task)/60,
    Clicks = mean(t5_clicks),
    Useful_raw = mean(t5_useful),
    Useful_percent = Useful_raw/7,
    UserFriendly_raw = mean(t5_user_friendly),
    UserFriendly_percent = UserFriendly_raw/7,
    Learned_raw = mean(t5_learned),
    Learned_percent = Learned_raw/7,
    Satisfied_raw = mean(t5_satisfied),
    Satisfied_percent = Satisfied_raw/7,
    Confident_raw = mean(t5_confident),
    Confident_percent = Confident_raw/7,
    Experienced_Difficulty_raw = sum(t5_exp_difficulty),
    Experienced_Difficulty_percent = Experienced_Difficulty_raw/N,
    difficulty_level_raw = mean(t5_difficulty_level, na.rm=TRUE),
    difficulty_level_percent = difficulty_level_raw/7
  )
#Move columsn and then use the second row as the header for the pivot columns--------


 Task5_Strict <- Task5_Strict %>%
      select("segment",everything())%>%
      select("Task",everything())

Task5_Strict_Pivot <- as.data.frame(t(Task5_Strict))
zTask5_Strict_Pivot <-Task5_Strict_Pivot[-2,]
colnames(Task5_Strict_Pivot)<-Task5_Strict_Pivot[2,]
```

In the end, my SuccessRate should be a percentage of the number of Advance who passed
`(t1_pass_fail = 1)` divided by the entire population of Advance, i.e. both
`(t1_pass_fail = 0, = 1).

I'm fairly noob so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to group by `t5_pass_fail`?

Comment: @stefan The reason I group by t5_pass_fail is I need to see the score differences between those who passed and those who failed the task. If there is a better way, I'm open to learning. Ideally, I'd like something that looks like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T_Ta3zeRsy3EHZrSp5xiVWBgwap0QiFO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RonakShah this is what I'm trying to obtain so I can output https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T_Ta3zeRsy3EHZrSp5xiVWBgwap0QiFO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the `SuccessRate` you can use `mean(t5_pass_fail == 1) * 100`.

```
library(dplyr) 

Task5_Strict <- cleanuxq4 %>% 
  dplyr:: select(("urespid_0"),("segment"),starts_with("t")) %>%
  group_by(segment,t5_pass_fail)%>%
  summarize(
    Task = "Task5",
    N =n(),
    SuccessRate = mean(t5_pass_fail == 1) * 100,
    UniquePages = (mean(t5_unique_pageviews)),
    Timedout_percent = sum(t5_effectiveness)/N,
    TimeonTask = mean(t5_time_task)/60,
    Clicks = mean(t5_clicks),
    Useful_raw = mean(t5_useful),
    Useful_percent = Useful_raw/7,
    UserFriendly_raw = mean(t5_user_friendly),
    UserFriendly_percent = UserFriendly_raw/7,
    Learned_raw = mean(t5_learned),
    Learned_percent = Learned_raw/7,
    Satisfied_raw = mean(t5_satisfied),
    Satisfied_percent = Satisfied_raw/7,
    Confident_raw = mean(t5_confident),
    Confident_percent = Confident_raw/7,
    Experienced_Difficulty_raw = sum(t5_exp_difficulty),
    Experienced_Difficulty_percent = Experienced_Difficulty_raw/N,
    difficulty_level_raw = mean(t5_difficulty_level, na.rm=TRUE),
    difficulty_level_percent = difficulty_level_raw/7
  )
```

Comment: Appreciate the attempt and I've tried that, but it still gives a percentage based on the group_by segment; t5_pass_fail. I just need to find a way to get the N for the segment and then / it by the breakdown.

Comment: @mdutton27 Well, it is difficult to share an answer without data. The data that you have shared is of `Task5_Strict` I suppose. We would need data for `cleanuxq4` to confirm if the answer works as per your expectation. You can try removing `t5_pass_fail` from `group_by` as mentioned by stefan.

Comment: perhaps I'm doing this wrong, but I did do a dput() of my problem, if that's not the right way to share data, please let me know for the future. However between you and Stefan, I did just figure it out as I needed to create a sum outside of the group by and then use them N within to obtain the proper %.  While it's not pretty (as a noob) you both helped, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both Stefan and Ronak, but I was attempting to do something illogical. I needed to move a sum of the segment outside of the group by and then use that to obtain a proper % within the group by.

The solution is at the very bottom:

```
    Task5_Strict <- cleanuxq4 %>% 
  dplyr:: select(("urespid_0"),("segment"),starts_with("t")) %>%
  group_by (segment,t5_pass_fail)%>%
  summarize(
    Task = "Task5",
    N =n(),
    UniquePages = (mean(t5_unique_pageviews)),
    Timedout_percent = sum(t5_effectiveness)/N,
    TimeonTask = mean(t5_time_task)/60,
    Clicks = mean(t5_clicks),
    Useful_raw = mean(t5_useful),
    Useful_percent = Useful_raw/7,
    UserFriendly_raw = mean(t5_user_friendly),
    UserFriendly_percent = UserFriendly_raw/7,
    Learned_raw = mean(t5_learned),
    Learned_percent = Learned_raw/7,
    Satisfied_raw = mean(t5_satisfied),
    Satisfied_percent = Satisfied_raw/7,
    Confident_raw = mean(t5_confident),
    Confident_percent = Confident_raw/7,
    Experienced_Difficulty_raw = sum(t5_exp_difficulty),
    Experienced_Difficulty_percent = Experienced_Difficulty_raw/N,
    difficulty_level_raw = mean(t5_difficulty_level, na.rm=TRUE),
    difficulty_level_percent = difficulty_level_raw/7
      )
    Task5_Strict <- mutate(Task5_Strict, zcount = sum(N))
    Task5_Strict <- mutate(Task5_Strict, SuccessRate =(N)/(zcount))
```